# Not able to install msxml6.msi on windows server 2012

Tags: windows, configuration, windows-server-2012, administration

I am not able to install msxml6.msi on windows server 2012. when i try to install the same it shows finish screen and not install the msi.

is this compatibility issue?

due to this not able to access assembly reference from GAC to access the classes in vb.net
getting this error while running the code "171  Type 'MSXML2.XMLHTTP' is not defined."

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes SAM this issue related with compatibility.
As per Microsoft installation steps:
It will only works on: Windows 2000 Service Pack 4, Windows Server 2003, Windows Server 2003 Service Pack 1, Windows XP Service Pack 1, Windows XP Service Pack 2